# How to simplify nested curly braces with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to simplify the nested curly braces in LaTeX.

In other words: `{ { ... } }` | `{ { { ... } } }` | etc. → `{ ... }`

For example, there is a section of TeX as follows:

```
$$\begin{aligned}
\pi &= \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty {\frac{1}{{{{16}^k}}}} \left( {\frac{8}{{8k + 2}} + \frac{4}{{8k + 3}} + \frac{4}{{8k + 4}} - \frac{1}{{8k + 7}}} \right)\\
\zeta (2) &= \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6} = \frac{3}{{16}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty {\frac{1}{{{{64}^k}}}} \left( {\frac{{16}}{{{{(6k + 1)}^2}}} - \frac{{24}}{{{{(6k + 2)}^2}}} - \frac{8}{{{{(6k + 3)}^2}}} - \frac{6}{{{{(6k + 4)}^2}}} + \frac{1}{{{{(6k + 5)}^2}}}} \right)\\
\zeta (3) &= \frac{9}{{224}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty {\frac{1}{{{{4096}^k}}}}
\left(\begin{aligned} 
&\frac{{1024}}{{{{(24k + 2)}^3}}} - \frac{{3072}}{{{{(24k + 3)}^3}}} + \frac{{512}}{{{{(24k + 4)}^3}}} + \frac{{1024}}{{{{(24k + 6)}^3}}} + \frac{{1152}}{{{{(24k + 8)}^3}}}\\
+& \frac{{384}}{{{{(24k + 9)}^3}}} + \frac{{64}}{{{{(24k + 10)}^3}}} + \frac{{128}}{{{{(24k + 12)}^3}}} + \frac{{16}}{{{{(24k + 14)}^3}}} + \frac{{48}}{{{{(24k + 15)}^3}}} + \frac{{72}}{{{{(24k + 16)}^3}}}\\
+& \frac{{16}}{{{{(24k + 18)}^3}}} + \frac{2}{{{{(24k + 20)}^3}}} - \frac{6}{{{{(24k + 21)}^3}}} + \frac{1}{{{{(24k + 22)}^3}}}\\
\end{aligned} \right)\\
\end{aligned}$$
```

The curly braces can be nested, and there may be spaces between the curly braces, but they must appear in pairs.

I tried the regular expression `{ *{((?>[^{}]+|{{[^}]*}})*)} *}`, but it cannot match all the cases.

How can I improve my regex, or this can't be done by regex, I must write a simple parser?

Comment: https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp has a `matchRecursive` method that might help you here.. js doesn't support subexpression calls which is needed to get nested matching.. for up to two level nesting you can use `/\{(?:[^{}]+|\{[^{}]+\})+\}/` which you can apply twice or extend it for three level nesting

Comment: If you just need to turn multiple `{` and `}` into single `{` and `}`, use `s.replace(/{+/g, '{').replace(/}+/g, '}')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that's wrong, for example if `s = '\\frac{{a}b}{c}'`

Comment: what do you do with `{{{{(24 + 3)}^3}}}` ?

Comment: You have a problem... You use regular expressions to solve it... Now you have two problems...

Comment: Could you also provide the expected output of the sample above?

Comment: Which engine? Your own regex includes an atomic cluster. It seems to be a PCRE flavor but you tagged javascript.

Comment: @GalAster for this 'frac{1}{{{{16}^k}}}}' you need this 'frac{1}{16}^k'?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with Regex in JavaScript is a mess.
First, since LaTeX is a structured file format a specialized parser would be more appropriate.
<sub>[siefkenj/latex-parser](https://github.com/siefkenj/latex-parser) pretty printer plugin (based on Michael Brade's LaTeX.js) could be the silver bullet answer to your problem. (However, there are some [problems parsing TeX](https://latex.js.org/limitations.html#when-parsing-tex-as-a-context-free-grammar)  in JS as well.. but that's a different story.)</sub>

Second, since JS' Regex engine does not support recursive patterns things get even more difficult. We could use a pattern like this (multiple times if needed) to get rid of excess braces:

```
 \{[ ]*(\{(?:[^{}]+|(?1))*\})[ ]*\}
```

Unfortunately, syntax like `(?1)` recursing the first subpattern or `(?R)` recursing the entire pattern cannot be used in JS. Nonetheless, as demonstrated by Steven Levithan

> Still, given that there is a known maximum amount of recursion that
> needs to be accounted for, it's quite possible. Here's the solution
> offered, which works just fine with JavaScript (it doesn't use any
> advanced regex features, actually):
>
> ```
> @[^{]+{(?:[^{}]|{[^{}]*})*}
> ```
>
> However, this works only if:
>
> - braces are always balanced, and ...

- [...only up to a known maximum level of recursion]

Adapting this to the problem at hand is not particularly hard, let's say for two levels of recursion

```
{[ ]*({(?:{(?:{.*?}|.)*?}|.)*?})[ ]*}
```

but there is a catch: Since we do not have an actual recursive pattern we need to 'recurse' the `.replace` of braces manually using a loop or helper function (like in the demo code below)

```js
const str = `\$\$\\begin{aligned}
\\pi &= \\frac{1}{2}\\sum\\limits_{k = 0}^\\infty {\\frac{1}{{{{16}^k}}}} \\left( {\\frac{8}{{8k + 2}} + \\frac{4}{{8k + 3}} + \\frac{4}{{8k + 4}} - \\frac{1}{{8k + 7}}} \\right)\\\\
\\zeta (2) &= \\frac{{{\\pi ^2}}}{6} = \\frac{3}{{16}}\\sum\\limits_{k = 0}^\\infty {\\frac{1}{{{{64}^k}}}} \\left( {\\frac{{16}}{{{{(6k + 1)}^2}}} - \\frac{{24}}{{{{(6k + 2)}^2}}} - \\frac{8}{{{{(6k + 3)}^2}}} - \\frac{6}{{{{(6k + 4)}^2}}} + \\frac{1}{{{{(6k + 5)}^2}}}} \\right)\\\\
\\zeta (3) &= \\frac{9}{{224}}\\sum\\limits_{k = 0}^\\infty {\\frac{1}{{{{4096}^k}}}}
\\left(\\begin{aligned}
&\\frac{{1024}}{{{{(24k + 2)}^3}}} - \\frac{{3072}}{{{{(24k + 3)}^3}}} + \\frac{{512}}{{{{(24k + 4)}^3}}} + \\frac{{1024}}{{{{(24k + 6)}^3}}} + \\frac{{1152}}{{{{(24k + 8)}^3}}}\\\\
+& \\frac{{384}}{{{{(24k + 9)}^3}}} + \\frac{{64}}{{{{(24k + 10)}^3}}} + \\frac{{128}}{{{{(24k + 12)}^3}}} + \\frac{{16}}{{{{(24k + 14)}^3}}} + \\frac{{48}}{{{{(24k + 15)}^3}}} + \\frac{{72}}{{{{(24k + 16)}^3}}}\\\\
+& \\frac{{16}}{{{{(24k + 18)}^3}}} + \\frac{2}{{{{(24k + 20)}^3}}} - \\frac{6}{{{{(24k + 21)}^3}}} + \\frac{1}{{{{(24k + 22)}^3}}}\\\\
\\end{aligned} \\right)\\\\
\\end{aligned}\$\$`;
const subst = `$1`;
const regex = /{[ ]*({(?:{(?:{.*?}|.)*?}|.)*?})[ ]*}/gm;

String.prototype.replacerec = function (pattern, what) {
    var newstr = this.replace(pattern, what);
    if (newstr == this)
        return newstr;
    return newstr.replace(pattern, what);
};

console.log(
  str.replacerec(regex, subst)
);
```

The combination of the pattern and the recursive function allows (theoretically) to clean any level of nested braces. If you are working with large files you might need to use an iterative approach or defer to a parser as suggested.

When I render the modified LaTeX code,e.g. [here](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo), I get the same (visual) output.

Answer (score 2):

A method independant of the nesting level, that uses placeholders.

```js
let latex = `$$\\begin{aligned}
\\pi &= \\frac{1}{2}\\sum\\limits_{k = 0}^\\infty {\\frac{1}{{{{16}^k}}}} \\left( {\\frac{8}{{8k + 2}} + \\frac{4}{{8k + 3}} + \\frac{4}{{8k + 4}} - \\frac{1}{{8k + 7}}} \\right)\\\\
\\zeta (2) &= \\frac{{{\\pi ^2}}}{6} = \\frac{3}{{16}}\\sum\\limits_{k = 0}^\\infty {\\frac{1}{{{{64}^k}}}} \\left( {\\frac{{16}}{{{{(6k + 1)}^2}}} - \\frac{{24}}{{{{(6k + 2)}^2}}} - \\frac{8}{{{{(6k + 3)}^2}}} - \\frac{6}{{{{(6k + 4)}^2}}} + \\frac{1}{{{{(6k + 5)}^2}}}} \\right)\\\\
\\zeta (3) &= \\frac{9}{{224}}\\sum\\limits_{k = 0}^\\infty {\\frac{1}{{{{4096}^k}}}}
\\left(\\begin{aligned}
&\\frac{{1024}}{{{{(24k + 2)}^3}}} - \\frac{{3072}}{{{{(24k + 3)}^3}}} + \\frac{{512}}{{{{(24k + 4)}^3}}} + \\frac{{1024}}{{{{(24k + 6)}^3}}} + \\frac{{1152}}{{{{(24k + 8)}^3}}}\\\\
+& \\frac{{384}}{{{{(24k + 9)}^3}}} + \\frac{{64}}{{{{(24k + 10)}^3}}} + \\frac{{128}}{{{{(24k + 12)}^3}}} + \\frac{{16}}{{{{(24k + 14)}^3}}} + \\frac{{48}}{{{{(24k + 15)}^3}}} + \\frac{{72}}{{{{(24k + 16)}^3}}}\\\\
+& \\frac{{16}}{{{{(24k + 18)}^3}}} + \\frac{2}{{{{(24k + 20)}^3}}} - \\frac{6}{{{{(24k + 21)}^3}}} + \\frac{1}{{{{(24k + 22)}^3}}}\\\\
\\end{aligned} \\right)\\\\
\\end{aligned}$$`;

// We protect each eventual literal tilde in the string
latex = latex.replace(/~/g, '~~');

// We replace each innermost substring enclosed between curly brackets by 
// a key. The key is used to store the matched substring in a Map.
let substrings = new Map(),
    repNo = 1; // No of replacements initialized with a fake value to enter
               // the loop.

// The replacement pattern checks if the substring isn't a key enclosed
// between curly brackets: in this case brackets are removed since the key
// is a placeholder for a substring already enclosed between curly brackets.

// This replacement is repeated until there's nothing to replace.    
for (let level = 0; repNo > 0; level++) {
    repNo = 0;
    latex = latex.replace(/{(?:(~l\d+n\d+~)|[^{}]*)}/g, (m, g1) => {
        // it's a key -> remove the brackets
        if (g1) 
            return g1; 
        
        // otherwise, replace with a placeholder (the key) and
        // store the substring in the Map.
        let key = `~l${level}n${repNo++}~`;
        substrings.set(key, m);
        return key;
    });
}

// Now, we can replace each placeholder key with its value.

do {
    repNo = 0;
    latex = latex.replace(/~l\d+n\d+~/g, (m) => {
        repNo++;
        return substrings.get(m);
    });
} while (repNo);

// restore the eventual escaped tildes
latex = latex.replace(/~~/g, '~');

console.log(latex);
```

Note that the format of the placeholder is totally arbitrary, feel free to build your own. For instance, there's no need to include the level inside it, but with it you can take a look at the string between the two loops and see the maximum nesting level.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job. Regular expressions can determine a regular language but they can't determine a context-free language like this one (parenthesis matching is one of the most common [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Well-formed_parentheses) of context-free languages). All in all, you need to write a stack-based parser (pushdown automaton).

Comment: agree, should be a state machine.